# Translation on a X,Z plane using variable axis relative to camera orientation

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine, translation, axis

I have a board on the world X,Z axis.
I have a camera that can rotate to look downward or upward and rotate left to right using the world Y axis.

Here's the camera rotation code:

```
float angle = (mouseX_Current - mouseX_ActionStart) * camRotationSpeedMod;
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(0.0f, angle, 0.0f, Space.World);

angle = (mouseY_Current - mouseY_ActionStart) * camRotationSpeedMod;
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, Space.Self);
```

Using mouse button down and a mouse position input(drag&Drop) I translate the camera in the world.  It receive a 2D vector that contain the X and Y value of the mouse(drag&drop) operation. Here's the code of the method I use :

```
private void CameraOnPlaneTranslation(Vector2 myVector)
{

   float cameraYPos = Camera.main.transform.position.y;

   Camera.main.transform.Translate(new Vector3(myVector[0], 0.0f, myVector[1]));

   Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position.x, cameraYPos, Camera.main.transform.position.z);
}
```

Problem : When my camera is not oriented directly toward the Z Axis(0.0f, Z, 0.0f) the translation vector I compute is incorrect.  I need to change the Y value of the vector so the camera don't move on the world Y axis.

Thanks

Comment: Your question has some ambiguities in it, and you are not likely to get responses until you make the question clearer.  By "drag&Drop", do you really mean "mouse move while the left button is down"?  In the second paragraph, when you say "my problem is", do you mean that is your problem statement (how you want it to work), or "the translation length changes but it ought not"?  Where does Vector2 myVector come from?  Is it being called in the mouseMove eventHandler?  Is it also a reduction of the mouseMove screen DeltaX, DeltaY from some other screen point?

Comment: By "drag&Drop", do you really mean "mouse move while the left button is down"?

->Yes<-

In the second paragraph, when you say "my problem is", do you mean that is your problem statement (how you want it to work)

->I mean that the same mouse drag&drop movement don't translate the camera of the same distance depending on camera orientation.<-

Where does Vector2 myVector come from?

->It comes from the drag&drop method that return the distance made by the mouse on the x and y axis.  So basically I create a new vector 3 with these values and use it to move the camera.<-

Comment: Thanks.  Based on this, I think my answer applies.  I expect the Translate method will update the camera Position value for you, so eliminate that call to Camera.main.transform.position =

Comment: In general the term "Drag and Drop" is used when moving data or a file reference from on application to another.  That is why your use of it here in this way required me to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by adding another GameObject that is affected only by the camera right/left rotations(world up vector) and the camera translations.

In the Awake method

```
cameraOrientation = new GameObject("cameraOrientation");
cameraOrientation.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position;
cameraOrientation.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
```

In the rotation method

```
float angle = (mouseX_Current - mouseX_ActionStart) * camRotationSpeedMod;
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(0.0f, angle, 0.0f, Space.World);
cameraOrientation.transform.Rotate(0.0f, angle, 0.0f, Space.World);

angle = (mouseY_Current - mouseY_ActionStart) * camRotationSpeedMod;
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, Space.Self);
```

And finally the translation method

```
cameraOrientation.transform.Translate(new Vector3(myVector[0], 0.0f, myVector[1]));
Camera.main.transform.position = cameraOrientation.transform.position;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Unity, but supposing it is similar to other 3D systems on these points, I will attempt an answer and hopefully not embarrass myself.

It looks like you /translate/ the camera position, then immediately /set/ the camera position, thus overwriting the work done by translate.  If this is the case, you should try setting `camera.main.transform.position` once (in the line after you create the Camera).  Then only apply `myVector` by the Translate call (as you have it).  Thus you should eliminate the third line of the method `Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position.x, cameraYPos, Camera.main.transform.position.z);`

After trying this, if it still does not do what you expect, see if it needs you to Update the view or Flush or ApplyTransform . . . anything that will make it understand you are done altering the transform and you are ready for it to process again with the updated transform.

Comment: I need to get the y position of the cam before the translation and reposition it to it's previous value so the camera don't move on the world Y value. That's the usage of the .transform.positon ...

When I reposition my camera I lose some of the translation vector length.
Which mean that the translation vector I actually use is not correct since I want it to be parallel to the X,Z plane of the board.

Comment: I am having a little trouble following your meaning when you say "so the camera doesn't move on the world Y value".  Are you intending to rotate the camera in a circle about a point at a fixed distance from the camera position?  If you are not moving in a circle, and you send transform.Y = 0.0f, then what moves the camera in Y?  (Note: I won't be able to respond until 8 AM Eastern US time.)

Comment: Ok, I'll reformulate.
I have a 2D board using X, Z world axis.
I have a camera that can rotate in any direction as long as it s aligned to the board

->float angle = (mouseX_Current - mouseX_ActionStart) * camRotationSpeedMod;
->Camera.main.transform.Rotate(0.0f, angle, 0.0f, Space.World);

->angle = (mouseY_Current - mouseY_ActionStart) * camRotationSpeedMod;
->Camera.main.transform.Rotate(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, Space.Self);

You have the translation code.

I hope this clarification help

Comment: I've reformulated the main question topic so it may be easier to read

Comment: Thanks for recomposing your question.  I think we have reached the limits of how I can help you.  I implemented something similar in WPF a few months ago, and it was a challenge.  But I never had to use a quaternion on the camera.  I did not see in your comments whether you tried eliminating your final line of code that resets the camera position.  I will be available on and off the rest of today, but I will only respond if I think I have something useful for you.

Comment: I can't eliminate the "camera position resetting" line since it correct the camera translation.  If I comment it the camera will go closer or farther to the board for a translation that should keep it a the same distance on the Y axis. Thanks a lot for your time.